# @InjectConnection not working for aTypeORM-SQL-Database, because its forRootAsync()

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am Registering my SQL-server in `app.module.ts` as follows:

```
 TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mssql',
        host: configService.get('HOST'),
        port: 1434,
        username: configService.get('USERNAME'),
        database: 'testdatabase', 
        password: configService.get('PASSWORD'),
        name: 'myDatabase', 
        entities: [],
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
```

In some other service I am Injecting the Database connection as follows:

```
  constructor(
    @InjectConnection("myDatabase") private readonly connection: Connection,
  ) { }
```

ThisService is inside a Module which is Imported in `app.module.ts`

If I register the TypeOrm Module without the async (just TypeOrmModule.forRoot()), and don't use `config.service` I can access the connection, but since I wanna use ConficService it registers the SQL-Server asynchronously. The connection doesn't exist yet when I inject it throwing the error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies 
of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument myDatabaseConnection at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.
```

I use the injected connection to run SQL-Queries on it.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `name` in the `@InjectConnection()`, then `name` also needs to be at the same level as `imports` and `useFactory` *as well as* inside the options. There's two things keeping track of the name here, Nest, which needs it for the injection tokens, and TypeORM, which needs it for the metadata storage.

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mssql',
        host: configService.get('HOST'),
        port: 1434,
        username: configService.get('USERNAME'),
        database: 'testdatabase', 
        password: configService.get('PASSWORD'),
        name: 'myDatabase', 
        entities: [],
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
      name: 'myDatabase',
    }),
```

Comment: Thats it! Damn. Can you please send me the page in the Docs where this is mentioned? I really took my time reading through everything I could find

Comment: [In the `Notice` block just a little ways down](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases)

Comment: The day will come that I read the docs and actually find what I'm looking for, cheers again!